# JSON array to one hot encoding in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the following:

```
car              colors
corvette         {"colors": ["red", "black"]}
forester         {"colors": ["white", "silver", "black"]}
```

I'd like to one hot encode the colors of each car like so:

```
car        black    red   white  silver  black
corvette       1      1       0       0      0
forester       1      0       1       1      0
```

What's a nice elegant way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(df.drop('colors', axis=1)
   .join(pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.colors.values)
                  ['colors'].explode())
            .sum(level=0)
        )
)
```

Output:

```
        car  black  red  silver  white
0  corvette      1    1       0      0
1  forester      1    0       1      1
```

Comment: Ran this with the following code:

    d = {'car': ['corvette', 'forester'], 'colors': [{'colors':['red', 'black']}, {'colors':['white', 'silver', 'black']}]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

and what you supplied above, received the following error:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'